# Apache: mod_disk_cache setup for specific url pattern with LocationMatch

Tags: apache, caching, config

i'm trying to setup mod_disk_cache for a url pattern. Server runs Apache/2.2.22

**Wanted:**

All requests to 'domain.com/location/anyHtmlFile' should be served from cache.

**Config**:

```
    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    SetEnv no-cache
```

**I want this to work:
"if url starts with "/location" do 'UnsetEnv no-cache'**

In the apache vhost I tried

```
    <LocationMatch "^/location/.+\.html$">
    <LocationMatch "/location/">
```

and desperately

```
    <LocationMatch "location">
             UnsetEnv no-cache
    </LocationMatch>


    <Location /location/>
     UnsetEnv no-cache
    </Location>
```

didn't work, too.

An html file in /location/ has following caching-relevant header attributes (Firefox):

```
    Cache-Control: max-age=14400, public
    Date    Wed, 05 Jun 2013 11:17:00 GMT
    Expires Wed, 05 Jun 2013 15:17:00 GMT
```

I have just recognized that the requestheader for the same file in chrome says

```
    Cache-Control:public
    Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
```

I'm setting Cache-Control to 'public' explicitely in the expires.conf.
I commented the global

```
     #SetEnv no-cache
```

out in my vhost config, but there are still both Cache-Controls in the header. But this shouldn't be the problem as I have 'CacheIgnoreCacheControl On', should it?

Any help?